# Find all links which _only_ contain an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

to add a click-to-zoom feature to images, I used the following code to toggle a class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageLinks = $('a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".bmp"]');
    if (imageLinks.children('img').length) {
        imageLinks.children('img').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('title', '(click to enlarge image)');
        });
        imageLinks.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).children('img').toggleClass('expanded');
        });
    }
    });
```

Now my problem is, I could have text links, like `<a href='file.png'>text</a>` as well on that page, and they are broken by this code.

Is there a way to select only image links (`<a href='file.png'><img src='file.png'></img></a>`) instead of all links to image files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fistly, this is not valid html; should be: `<a href='file.png'><img src='file.png'/></a>` or `<a href='file.png'><img src='file.png'></a>`

Comment: could you not just select the img tags inside the a tag, then select the parent. The selector would be something like: $("a > img") or $("a img") depending whether the image must be the direct descendant or not

Comment: roasted: sorry, I was just trying to make the point that there are links only containing an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `has` statement:

```
var imageLinks = $('a').filter(':has(img)');
```

Or the same:

```
var imageLinks = $('a:has(img)');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
var $images = $('a > img');
$images.attr('title', '(click to enlarge image)');
$images.parent().click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('img').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UHkh7/

You can change the selector to `'a img'` if the img is not always a direct descendent of the a tag, however you will then need to change `$images.parent()` to `$images.parents('a')[0]`

Comment: Didn't work here. No classes were toggled at all, both text and image links resulted in the image itself being opened.

Comment: OK my fault! After adapting to `$images.parent()` your solution works as well!

Comment: If you can try and create a jsFiddle that doesn't work I will take a look to spot the issue.